# sending partial form data using JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to send a `customer ID` do a quick check if the user has any violations under his name. when hard coding any customer ID I am getting the expected results back into my console, I want to show that on a small `alert` box, here is my code so far:

**HTML**:

```
<strong>Customer ID:</strong>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="custidno" id='cust' autocomplete="off" onkeypress="myFunction()"  placeholder="Customer ID" value="{{ old('custidno') }}">
<input type="button" id="violationchecker" class="btn btn-info" style="background:#692563;color:white;" value="Check for Violations">
```

**Script**:

```
var path = "{{ url('violationcheck') }}";
var singleValues = $( "#cust" ).val();

$("#violationchecker").click(function() {
   $.get(path, { custidno : singleValues }
     ,function(data){
         alert(checked)
   });
});
```

**Controller**:

```
public function violationcheck(Request $request)
{
   $checked = DB::table('violations')
             ->select('severity',DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
             ->where("custidno",$request->custidno)
             ->groupBy('severity')
             ->get();
   return response()->json($checked);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Place singleValues variable inside click event function. As below:

```
    var path = "{{ url('violationcheck') }}";   
    $("#violationchecker").click(function() {
       var singleValues = $( "#cust" ).val();
       $.get(path, { custidno : singleValues }
         ,function(data){
             alert(checked)
       });
    });
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am can see the values being returned in the console now, but not on the alert box. do you mind telling me why is that?

Comment: alert(data) not like alert(checked). or you can do console.log(data);